# E-commerce production website testing checkout approach

Tags: e-commerce

Not sure if I'm posting this in the correct Stack website, but I've been developing e-commerce websites for about 10 years now, and I recently developed a pretty large one.

New enhancements get tested and deployed all the time, but when testing a checkout enhancement I always have to use my actual credit card to complete the checkout process.

Does anyone have a rock solid approach for being able to test on production without having to process a real card? I don't want anyone else to be able to use the card i.e. customers.

If there is a Laravel specific answer to this it would really help, but an approach would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the larger online credit card processors have developer "sandboxes" so you can easily do this. for example: https://developer.authorize.net/sandbox/

Comment: We are using Stripe. We develop on local and test using sandbox credentials, then deploy to staging and test using sandbox credentials, then deploy to production and test using live credentials. Because the production website is live and taking orders, we cannot simply switch to the test key (from the live key) to test on production. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue and my best idea, I think, is to use a pre-paid VISA card. You can load any amount on to it and then cancel/refund the transaction as you please. I was worried my fraud score would be affected with multiple cancellations against my card.

Comment: Thanks @radrichtea. That's a good alternative to developing something into the website. It doesn't solid the issue, but a smart immediate way to be able to test with minimal cost. Question(s), don't the chargebacks cost you money though? Doesn't the payment provider still charge the 2.9% (or whatever) for processing the payment?